# Solve a cubic polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I've been having trouble with this question:

Solve the equation, $$5x^3 - 24x^2 + 9x + 54 = 0$$  given that two of its roots are equal.

I've tried methods such as Vieta's formula and simultaneous equations, assuming the roots are: $a$, $a$, $b$, but I am still unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if two roots are equal to $a$, then the derivative of your polynomial has $a$ as a root. To see why, just write $P=(x-a)^2 Q$ and differentiate. Hence, you have only an equation of degree 2 to solve.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to use a method not involving calculus.

Comment: @missiledragon In that case you can use Horners Synthetic Division method.

Comment: Then the simplest who be to develop $5(x-a)^2(x-b)$ and identify coefficients.

Comment: I got up to that, but I'm not sure how to identify the coefficients.

Comment: Differentiate once, then find the gcd of the derivative and the original function. $x-a$ will be the common factor. Then divide out to find $b$ (or just find $b=-54/5a^2$)

Comment: I'm not supposed to differentiate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x-a)^2(x-b) = (x^2-2ax+a^2)(x-b)=x^3-(2a+b)x^2+a(a+2b)x-a^2b$$
$$=x^3-\frac{24}{5}x^2+\frac{9}{5}x+\frac{54}{5}$$

Then
$$2a+b=\frac{24}{5}$$
$$a+2b=\frac{9}{5a}$$

Multiply the first by 2 and subtract:
$$3a=\frac{48}{5}-\frac{9}{5a}$$

Now it should not be difficult to find $a$. Of course this equation gives two possible values of $a$, and only one is right (you have to check with your degree three equation).

Comment: Thanks for the help :D
I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

By Vieta's formula, $$\begin{cases}2a+b=\dfrac{24}5\\a^2+2ab=a(a+2b)=\dfrac95\\a^2b=-\dfrac{54}5 \end{cases}$$

Notice that $0$ is not a root of the original equation, so both $a,b$ are nonzero. Divide the second equation by the third equation to get $\dfrac{a+2b}{ab}=\dfrac2a
+\dfrac1b=-\dfrac1{6}$. Multiplying by the first equation, we have $$(2a+b)(\dfrac2a
+\dfrac1b)=5+2(\dfrac ba+\dfrac ab)=-\dfrac45 $$

Let $\dfrac ba=t$, then the above equation becomes $$5+2(t+\dfrac1t)=-\dfrac45\implies 10t^2+29t+10=(5t+2)(2t+5)=0$$

Hence $t=-\dfrac25$ or $-\dfrac52$. If $t=-\dfrac25, 2a+b=2a+at=\dfrac85a=\dfrac{24}5,$ so $a=3$. On the other hand, if $t=-\dfrac52, 2a+b=-\dfrac12a=\dfrac{24}5,$ so $a=-\dfrac{48}5$. But from the third equation we must have $b\lt 0$, and then $a,b$ are both $\lt 0$, so $2a+b\lt 0$ and then the first equation cannot hold. Therefore $a=3, b=-\dfrac{6}5$ are the roots of the original cubic.